# Scala Play and Multi Project SBT Builds

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I created a scala play project like this

```
activator new foo play-event-sourcing-starter
```

the project was generated successfully and I can go inside and easily compile and run the app.

However what I want is that I should have a multi project sbt build. I googled and found this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects

But this is not the same as what I want because here they have play as the root project. whereas what I want is that I have an empty root project with a build.sbt file and then multiple "peer" projects. One of them is play.

So I changed the steps to

```
mkdir -p LearnPlay/project
cd LearnPlay
activator new foo play-event-sourcing-starter
```

Now I went inside foo and moved the `build.sbt` to the LearnPlay directory. I also moved the `build.properties` and `plugins.sbt` files into LearnPlay/project folder.

I edited the build.sbt file so that the root project becomes

```
lazy val root = (project in file("foo")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

However now sbt cannot compile the project anymore and it cannot find any of the play framework dependencies.

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.10;2.5.9: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-netty-server_2.10;2.5.9: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-logback_2.10;2.5.9: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.10;2.5.9: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.10;2.5.9: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
```

These are the contents of my plugins.sbt file. The resolver is defined correctly so I am not sure why sbt will not be able to find the dependencies after the file was moved from sub-project to root project. it was able to resolve everything when the file was in the project directory of the foo project.

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.9")

// web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that gave me some ideas what's the problem there is:

```
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.10;2.5.9: not found
```

Aren't you surprised, that **sbt** tries to download the version of play server for Scala **2.10**, which doesn't exist for Play **2.5.x**, since it's already out of lifecycle.

In my projects this is happening, if I'm not specifying scala version in `build.sbt` or set it to the **2.10**, e.g.

```
lazy val root = (project in file("foo")).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.10.6",
```

so, I think you just need to add `scalaVersion` parameter and set it to something from **2.11.x** or **2.12.x**

Comment: You are right but its a little surprising because the scalaVersion was specified in the sbt project although not directly on the root project itself. It was able to pick the right scala version when it was in root project... but not when it was using the directory.